# checking for missing element on loading page

Tags: angular

Using angular 7, the form looks like below

```
<mat-form-field>
    <textarea  matInput 
        [(ngModel)]="dataObj.member.name" 
            name="memberId" disabled></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

`dataObj` is holding all data like below

```
{
"somekey": "someValue"
"id": "5c7abba",
  "member": {
    "name": "test",
    "id": "5c76de28"
  }
}
```

Sometimes, the member can be missing from dataObj, in such cases, angular form complains to load. 
I tried fixing with

*`ngIf="dataObj.member`"

```
<mat-form-field>
    <textarea  matInput *ngIf="dataObj.member"
        [(ngModel)]="dataObj.member.name" 
            name="memberId" disabled></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

But this not works. Want to achieve, if the member is missing, form to show blank filed

dataObj return from service api.

```
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getObj(); 
      }

  getObj() {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    this.objService.getObj(id)
      .subscribe(obj => this.obj = obj);
  }
```

Comment: Show your component code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and handle in the following manor.

**solution**

```
<div *ngIf="dataObj && dataObj.member">
  <textarea  matInput 
    <mat-form-field>
      [(ngModel)]="dataObj.member.name" name="memberId" disabled>
    </mat-form-field>
  </textarea>
</div>
```

**explination**

This should check the both of the values exist before accessing them and leave you without an error, if they do not exist the `<mat-form-field>` will not be inserted and therefore will not try and access the undefined fields which would result in the errors.

I would recommend whatever is populating `dataObj` should be done within the [ngOnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) lifecycle hook which is run before the view in initialised, this should help with the value not being defined within the view. That way the checks with the `&&` are just a precaution.

**edit**

```
public dataObj = {}; 

public ngOnInit(): void 
{
    const id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;

    this.objService.getObj(id).subscribe(obj => 
    {
        this.dataObj = obj;
        console.log(this.dataObj); // can check values here.
    });
}
```

Just noticed in the controller you are working with `this.obj` but in the template you are using `dataObj`. The edit here uses the same for both. Ensure to do the sam.

Comment: ngOnInit() {
    this.getObj(); 
  }  ... My ngOnInit is like this, how I can manipulate of access dataObj once my this.getObj() over

Comment: if you edit in your ngOnInit to the question will be able to help, guessing getObj is a http request ? If so please edit in call in service aswell

Comment: Did this help??

Comment: Glad it helped  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in such a way

```
 [(ngModel)]="dataObj?.member?.name"
```

This will take it as optional field and will skip it if dataObj has no member or name

Comment: this throws more error like Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used